# HDMI is not displayed in the "Sound" settings on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I need some assistance, I have 2 laptops, a Toshiba and a DELL XPS M1330, the problem is using my DELL laptop, when I use the HDMI cable to use the TV as monitor the display works fine however the sound only work in the laptop speakers I can't use the TV speakers.

When I go to "Sound" settings to select the HDMI in the "Play sound through", I can't select the HDMI because it never show up. I can only see, "headphones and speakers".

So as a summary the, display works but the sound it doesn't in the TV. Any ideas?

Comment: This sound completely foolish but when you check sound options with Dell laptop is HDMI cable attached at both ends in respective ports and display is on?

Answer (score 23):

I follow the below workaround whenever I connect laptop to a TV:

1. Connect HDMI cable to TV and switch on the TV.
2. Run the below command on a console (It worked without `sudo`)

   ```
   pulseaudio -k
   ```
3. Open Sound settings, you should see "HDMI/Display Port" entry under Output tab.

Comment: this is works on ubuntu 14.04 using my r9 390. thanks

Comment: I love you bro!

Comment: this worked on 19.04

Comment: Works on 20.04 as well

Comment: Not working anymore in 22.04 `pulseaudio -k` -> 
`W: [pulseaudio] caps.c: Normally all extra capabilities would be dropped now, but that's impossible because PulseAudio was built without capabilities support.`

Answer (score 1):

To get HDMI audio working on Ubuntu, please download the deb file *for your version of Ubuntu* from this link:

[https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/) and install it via cli or the software centre.

1. For older packages go to page: [https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages)
2. Then force reload alsa using the following command : `sudo alsa force-reload`
3. After that, select HDMI from the sound menu as shown below (for me this option appeared only after installing the above mentioned package)

   [image]

**Please note** HDMI audio function tested on Intel graphics only on a Lenovo Flex2 14 laptop

Comment: No luck when trying this on ubuntu 15.04...

Comment: No luck trying this on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your laptop has dual graphics which may need you to install the Nvidia binary driver and Bumblebee from this guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried the steps mentioned in the link however the issue remains.

Comment: Not sure why you suggest installing NVIDIA binaries -- nothing in the Oso's question seems to suggest this is an NVIDIA card.  I believe the Dell he describes, the XPS M1330, has integrated Intel GMA graphics (http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-xps-m1330/specs/)

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:
**Reinstall Alsa and Pulse Audio**

Open an Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ATL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Try to reinstall pulse audio and Alsa, open terminal and enter the following commands:

Purge Alsa and Pulse audio using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Now install again Alsa and Pulse Audio:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Then, reload Alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Done, if it is not working try the following:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Pleas note, that driver is **NOT** updated for Ubuntu 14.04 yet.

Comment: I tried your solution but increased problems than solving it.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem. Pulseaudio was not running at startup because my home directory was owned by root. I changed the owner and the sound came back.

Comment: -1 Explain the process of taking ownership of your home directory. If someone ran `sudo chown -R $HOME` without thinking, they could break their system.