# My laptop doesn't show the HDMI among the sound output options

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio

My laptop doesn't show the HDMI among the sound output options, so I was trying to find a way to play sound through HDMI.

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/474565/263726) on the question "HDMI is not displayed in the “Sound” settings on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS", and for an reason unknown to me, the user has posted a solution that doesn't work for 14.04 LTS (and doesn't work for OP):

> Please note, that driver is not updated for Ubuntu 14.04 yet.

Now my PulseAudio setting interface looks broken, shows no output options and the taskbar doesn't show the audio icon anymore. I don't even need the HDMI audio anymore.

I would've just commented it on the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/474565/263726), but I don't have 50 rep.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling my Ubuntu. I'll leave this question here, because if someone happens to know the answer, it might help other people in the future.