# after reinstall Alsa and Pulse Audio, system setting missing

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I followed: [HDMI is not displayed in the "Sound" settings on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472258/hdmi-is-not-displayed-in-the-sound-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
this article to reinstall alsa and pulse audio, because when using hdmi, the sound not work.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
[sudo] password for william: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 python3-pyudev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  alsa-base* indicator-sound* libcanberra-pulse* osspd* osspd-pulseaudio*
  pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-x11*
  unity-control-center* unity-control-center-signon*
  webaccounts-extension-common* xul-ext-webaccounts*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 12 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,351 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,209 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gnome-control-center amd64 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 [464 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgoa-backend-1.0-1 amd64 3.10.3-0ubuntu1 [198 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gnome-control-center-data all 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 [1,216 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gnome-settings-daemon amd64 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 [472 kB]
Fetched 2,351 kB in 4s (502 kB/s)              
(Reading database ... 626709 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Purging configuration files for alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing xul-ext-webaccounts (0.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing webaccounts-extension-common (0.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Purging configuration files for webaccounts-extension-common (0.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing unity-control-center-signon (0.1.7~+14.04.20140211.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-control-center.
(Reading database ... 626611 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-control-center_1%3a3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-control-center (1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
(Reading database ... 626659 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libcanberra-pulse:amd64 (0.30-0ubuntu3) ...
Purging configuration files for libcanberra-pulse:amd64 (0.30-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing osspd (1.3.2-5) ...
 * Stopping OSS Proxy Daemon osspd                                               [ OK ] 
Purging configuration files for osspd (1.3.2-5) ...
Removing osspd-pulseaudio (1.3.2-5) ...
Removing pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Removing pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Removing unity-control-center (14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1) ...
Purging configuration files for unity-control-center (14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing indicator-sound (12.10.2+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1) ...
Purging configuration files for indicator-sound (12.10.2+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Purging configuration files for pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 626270 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgoa-backend-1.0-1_3.10.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.10.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-control-center-data.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-control-center-data_1%3a3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-control-center-data (1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-settings-daemon.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-settings-daemon_3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-settings-daemon (3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.10.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gnome-control-center-data (1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1) ...
Setting up gnome-settings-daemon (3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2) ...
Setting up gnome-control-center (1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
william@William-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 python3-pyudev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  pulseaudio-module-x11
Suggested packages:
  apmd alsa-oss oss-compat pavumeter paman pavucontrol paprefs
  pulseaudio-module-raop pulseaudio-esound-compat
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alsa-base pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
Need to get 859 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,168 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main alsa-base all 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4 [151 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main pulseaudio amd64 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 [692 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main pulseaudio-module-x11 amd64 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 [15.9 kB]
Fetched 859 kB in 2s (317 kB/s)                 
Selecting previously unselected package alsa-base.
(Reading database ... 626673 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio.
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio_1%3a4.0-0ubuntu11.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio-module-x11.
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio-module-x11_1%3a4.0-0ubuntu11.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Adding user pulse to group audio
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
william@William-PC:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-seq snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-seq snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-device snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-seq snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

my system setting is messed up:

[image]

Please help , how can I get my system settings back ?

Comment: You have removed a lot of packages. Install this packages again. Look for `Removing` in the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you purge `alsa-base pulseaudio` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

This remove the following packages:

```
  alsa-base* indicator-sound* libcanberra-pulse* osspd* osspd-pulseaudio*
  pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-x11*
  unity-control-center* unity-control-center-signon*
  webaccounts-extension-common* xul-ext-webaccounts*
```

This leads to this miss up since you remove the  `unity-control-center*` and the `unity-control-center-signon*` and the other packages listed above.

In order to solve this problem you should install those packages again.

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base* indicator-sound* libcanberra-pulse* osspd* osspd-pulseaudio* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-x11* unity-control-center* unity-control-center-signon* webaccounts-extension-common* xul-ext-webaccounts*
```

If this make some problem then it's better to install one package at once.

Comment: This is sofar only valid work around after this purge mesh.
"sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio"
It had nearly emptied my System setting contents.

Thanks Maythux a lot!

Comment: @vimalkrishna Have you read the question before?!!! His system settings were already in mess