# No sound using Displayport to HDMI connected to TV Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi, tv, displayport

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a desktop connected to a TV HDMI input using Displayport as an output from the PC. The problem is that I don't have sound. Even when I tried to change the sound hardware I didn't find any digital or HDMI/Displayport hardware. I only have Speakers and Analog output!

I tried this thread but didn't work for me.

[HDMI is not displayed in the "Sound" settings on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472258/hdmi-is-not-displayed-in-the-sound-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: did you find any solution?